# Archive tasks at anytime by any user

Tags: security, tasks

I have a requirement where I need to archive tasks at any time by any user. Salesforce archive  duration is one year but I should be able set a task as atchived by me at any time.  Or is is there any way to prevent the records from displayed from reports listviews and other views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Archived" is a special system term that not just removes the tasks from list views, but also from normal SOQL queries, the calendar, synchronizations, etc. There's no way to influence which tasks and events become archived, except to set their due date at least one year prior and wait for them to archive automatically, which should be within 24 hours of setting the expired date.

You can, of course, create a custom field, perhaps a checkbox, and filter your reports and list views using that checkbox, but it will have no bearing on the actual "archived" status of the activity. The only way to actually cause an archival to occur is through setting the date significantly far back enough that the archival process will flag it as such on the next pass.